# Thinkpad x220 network switch not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, thinkpad

I recently got a used Thinkpad x220, I had everything working fine under Windows 10. I flipped the network switch on the side which as expected cut the internet connection. The issue is after flipping the switch back to on it is still seems to be off. Wifi shows as off and the Windows network troubleshooting tool recoginizes it as a wifi being turned off on the computer. I tried fn + F5 and that did not reenanle networking.

I tried rebooting the computer and flipping the switch a couple more times none of which worked. I can connect fine via ethernet.

Is there anything else I can try or is the network switch apparently broken?

Comment: Check in Network & Sharing center if adapter marked as disabled and try to re-enable it. Check also if adapter present in device manager

Comment: @Alex still not working after disable and reenable. The network adapter is listed in device manager.

Comment: Try to delete(uninstall) WiFi adapter from device manager, then restart computer, it should reinstall driver. BTW, do you see any pop/notification on screen when turning hardware WiFi switch? Sometimes it get stuck, try to press it toward computer when you switching it